# How to prevent race-condition when operating on the same data from a Room database using AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room, race-condition

I'm working on an android application that stores custom "TimeSet" objects in a database. When interacting with the table I use `AsyncTask` objects to insert and update rows. During testing, I find that these tasks must run in a particular order (e.g. a row must be inserted into the database before it is updated) and when they don't occur as expected, the tests fail.

From what I understand, `AsyncTask` runs on a "first come first served" basis. Ideally, I want the `updateAsyncTask()` to wait until there is actually some row in the table before it occurs. I have tried using lock objects to prevent this, but it has not worked out for me. I also saw a suggestion that involved sending some kind of message `onPostExecute()`, but I am unsure how to make it work for my code. I am relatively new to working with **Room** in Android and I'm finding this area particularly confusing.

Typical Test method which updates a row:

```
@Test
public void replaceTodaysTime() {
    mActivityRule.getActivity().mTimeSetViewModel.insert(oldTimeSet);
    mActivityRule.getActivity().sendTimeToDatabase(NEW_WORSE_TIME, EXERCISE_NAME, MOCK_DATE);
    TimeSet timeSet = mActivityRule.getActivity().mTimeSetViewModel.getByName(EXERCISE_NAME);
    assertEquals(NEW_WORSE_TIME, timeSet.getTodaystime());
    assertNotSame(oldTimeSet.getTodaystime(), timeSet.getTodaystime());
}
```

The `ViewModel` is linked to the `TimeSetRepository`

```
public class TimeSetRepository {

public void insert(TimeSet timeSet) {
    insertAsyncTask iat = new insertAsyncTask(mTimeSetDao);
    timeSetLock.lock();
    try {
        iat.execute(timeSet);
    } finally {
        if(iat.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            timeSetLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public void updateByName(TimeSet timeSet) {
    while (mAllTimeSets == null && mAllTimeSets.isEmpty()){
        //do nothing!
    }
    updateAsyncTask uat = new updateAsyncTask(mTimeSetDao);
    timeSetLock.lock();
    try {
        uat.execute(timeSet);
    } finally {
        if(uat.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            timeSetLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}


static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<TimeSet, Void, Void> {

    private TimeSetDao mAsyncTimeSetDao;

    insertAsyncTask(TimeSetDao dao) {
        mAsyncTimeSetDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final TimeSet... timeSets) {
        mAsyncTimeSetDao.insertTimeSet(timeSets[0]);
        return null;
    }

}

private static class updateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<TimeSet, Void, Void> {
    private TimeSetDao mAsyncTimeSetDao;
    updateAsyncTask(TimeSetDao dao) {
        mAsyncTimeSetDao = dao;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final TimeSet... timeSets) {
        mAsyncTimeSetDao.updateLastAccessed(timeSets[0].getExercisename(), timeSets[0].getLastaccessed());
        mAsyncTimeSetDao.updateTodaysTime(timeSets[0].getExercisename(), timeSets[0].getTodaystime());
        return null;
    }

}


}
```

I expect the `oldTimeSet` to be inserted into the database, then to have the row updated, then finally to retrieve the row as an object. When this works, the `todaysTime` variable has changed. However, it does not always work, sometimes it returns the time from the `oldTimeSet`, sometimes `timeSet` in the test method is a null object, and so on. I am performing similar actions in other tests with similar results. I think if I can solve this particular issue, I should be able to adapt the solution to the rest of my tests.

Thank you for your help.